# denormalise reverse processStrategy

Tags: normalizr

I have an API that gives out data like this with the attributes in a fields property.

```
{
records: [
    {
    id: "123",
    fields: {
        author: {
        id: "1",
        name: "Paul"
        },
        title: "My awesome blog post",
        comments: [
        {
            id: "324",
            commenter: {
            id: "2",
            name: "Nicole"
            }
        }
        ]
    }
    }
]
};
```

When normalizing, I now handle this with a simple `processStrategy: (input, parent, key) => input.fields` but I would like denormalise this again so that the denormalised entities to contain this fields structure because the API expects it this way.

So far denormalising my normalised data with `const denormalizedData = denormalize([123], [article], normalizedData.entities)` omits the field:

```
[
{
    "author": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Paul"
    },
    "title": "My awesome blog post",
    "comments": [
    {
        "id": "324",
        "commenter": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Nicole"
        }
    }
    ]
}
]
```

I cannot find anything in the [api docs](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/blob/6c5af279cc890a94fb7cde53a32811ccc7c2e28b/docs/api.md) on how to add extra processing on denormalisation, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Because `processStrategy` is intended for pre-processing of data during the normalization process, it is not going to be executed during the denormalization. For your use case, I would not use this feature and simply structure your schemas as follows:

```
const { schema, denormalize, normalize } = normalizr;
const user = new schema.Entity("users");
const comment = new schema.Entity("comments", { commenter: user });
const commentList = [comment];
const post = new schema.Entity("posts", {
  fields: { author: user, comments: commentList }
});
const postList = [post];
const mockApiResponse = {
  records: [
    {
      id: "123",
      fields: {
        author: {
          id: "1",
          name: "Paul"
        },
        title: "My awesome blog post",
        comments: [
          {
            id: "324",
            commenter: {
              id: "2",
              name: "Nicole"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

const normalizedResponse = normalize(mockApiResponse.records, postList);
const denormalizedResponse = denormalize(
  normalizedResponse.result,
  postList,
  normalizedResponse.entities
);

console.log("normalizedResponse", normalizedResponse);
console.log("denormalizedResponse", denormalizedResponse);
```

This will give you the result you are looking for. If for some reason, you need to stick to your current implementation, I would recommend implementing a transform on your request prior to sending it back to the server. As an example, `axios` solves this with their [`transformRequest`](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) feature.